# How to display Groupboxes in order of selection

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to a collection of groupboxes varying on the user selection. for example; there will be 7 groupboxes, the user can enable however many they want and in what order they want. So i want the selected groupbox B to appear at the bottom of the previously selected groupbox A yet when A is unselected B moves up the form to where A was. 
In my mind i want it to behave similar to HTML items. 
This will be done in WPF, coding in C#.

Comment: Have you got an example of what you are trying to achieve? Perhaps a website link to something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack these groupboxes in a stackpanel with orientation=vertical. You can then set the Visibility of the groupboxex to the users decision and wpf will make the rest for you "by magic".

Little sample here:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <GroupBox x:Name="First" Visibility="Visible" Header="First">
            <Label>First</Label>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="Second" Visibility="Collapsed" Header="Second">
            <Label>Second</Label>
        </GroupBox>
        <GroupBox x:Name="Third" Visibility="Visible" Header="Third">
            <Label>Third</Label>
        </GroupBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks alot =)

Answer (score 0):

Put your GroupBoxes in a collection of some kind and databind that collection to a cusomised ListView. Whenever the selected state of a GroupBox changes update the view of that ListView to sort them based on your requirements. Unfortunately I am not good enough to provide a working sample in the time I have, sry.